# .htaccess multiple parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm currently working on a site, where I'm trying to create more user friendly urls.

However, .htaccess is not anything that I'm good at, so I'm looking for some help.

I managed getting 1 parameter to work following other guides, but I'm unable to get multiple to work.

What I currently have in my .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/?$ user.php?id=$1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} user\.php
RewriteRule ^user\.php - [F]
```

So I'm currently getting returned the ID which is inserted, in a URL such as /user/someone

I would like to know how I could add it so that it would read a page as well?`

So it would be /user/someone/about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user\/(\w+)(\/(\w+))?(\/(\w+))?\/?$ user.php?id=$1&second=$3&third=$5
```